# Cómo saber desde que botón se llamó una función en C#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy creando unos paneles con un botón, y busco que dentro de estos paneles haya un botón que elimine el panel al que pertenece

```
private int count = 0;

private void crearVenta()
        {
            Panel panelInfo = new Panel();
            panelInfo.Name = $"panelInfo_{count}";
            Button deleteButton = new Button();
            deleteButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Metodo_Click);
            deleteButton.Name = $"deleteButton_{count}";
            panelInfo.Controls.Add(deleteButton);
     
            count++;
        }

private void Metodo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Función eliminar panel padre
        }
```

Trato de asignarle un nombre conforme el contador `count` va aumentando para poder acceder a él con este nombre, necesito que me identifique cuál fue el botón que se activó para poder acceder al panel padre y eliminarlo... ¿cómo lo puedo hacer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void Metodo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Button btn = (Button)sender;
   btn.Parent.Visible = false;
   //btn.Parent.MetodoX();
   //btn.Parent.PropiedadX;
}
```

Casteas al tipo **Button** el **parámetro sender** y una vez que obtienes ese botón, accedes a su **propiedad Parent**, la cual accede al control contenedor de nuestro botón, que en este caso es un **Panel**, y puedes hacer con el **Panel** lo que desees a través de esta **propiedad Parent**, que en este caso nos da acceso al **Panel** contenedor del botón.

Comment: Te amo con mi vida

Comment: @GiacomoFranco, jajaj, no olvides tu voto(flechita hacia arriba) ;)